# Indesign to word conversion doesn't look good

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I have an InDesign letterhead design that I want to convert into an editable word document.  I have converted it to a PDF which looks fine, but when I convert it to a Word document, the faded colour down the side (which would be behind writing of a letter) becomes bold and so isn't ideal or useful for the Word document letterhead template.  Any advice?

Comment: Hi Amy, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat]
(http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Honestly, the best way to create letterhead in Word is to design it in Word from scratch. I have encountered way too many instances of really nice stationery which can't be ported, and then clients get ticked off that they can't have the nice design on their PCs. Don't promise what you can't deliver. Either the client only gets pre-printed letterhead or design within Word's limitations.

Comment: Could you place an image of how it looks in InDesign and how it comes out in Word?

Answer (score 1):

Amy. sounds as though the design should be in the header/footer of the document. Word doesn't have layers, as such, the header footer does something similar though. The conversion process won't create a header/footer so you'll need to do this manually.

David

Answer (score -2):

As you said, you've converted into **PDF** that looks fine. Why don't you try the **converted PDF to word doc** again